# Elasticsearch filter fields by data

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, field, response

I need to use an API with an elasticsearch backend. I don't have any controls about that server but I need to reduce the fields I get in the responses. I already figured out how to use "filter_path" and how to include specific fields by their name. But I didn't find anything about how to dismiss specific fields by data. I already tried using nested terms but with no positive results.

My actual JSON query looks like this:

```
{
"_source" : ["field1", "field2", "field3.1", "field3.2"],
    "query": { 
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the current output like this:

```
{
"hits": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "_source": {
                "field1": "data",
                "field2": "data",
                "field3": [
                    {
                        "field3.1": "SPECIALDATA",
                        "field3.2": "SPECIALDATA"
                    },
                    {
                        "field3.1": "data",
                        "field3.2": "data"
                    },
                    {
                        "field3.1": "data",
                        "field3.2": "data"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

I only want field3.1 and 3.2 with the SPECIALDATA in it. All other fields with 3.1 and 3.2 should be dismissed.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I have to change my query to achieve this?

Comment: what about this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fielddata_filtering.html

Comment: Thank you, I missed that section.